# laravel - switch language with translate url based on DB value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.3
and I make link in the header to switch language as follow

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ str_replace(env('REDIRECT').'/'.$locale, 
$locale == 'en' ? env('REDIRECT').'/ar' : env('REDIRECT').'/en', 
\URL::full()) }}">
<i class="fa fa-globe i.con-lang" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span class="language-text">{{ $locale == 'en' ? 'ع' : 
'en' }}</span>
</a>
```

and the URL is generated from database like

```
http://localhost/example/public/en/service/mobile-app-development
```

note that [ (service) => i get it's translation from DB

```
mobile-app-development => translated from DB also
      ]
```

alternative URL in another language ( Arabic ) is:

```
http://localhost/example/public/ar/تطبيقات-الموبايل/الخدمة
```

and my route like

```
Route::get(getSlugByKey('service').'/{service_slug}', 
'HomeController@service')->name('service');
```

such that getSlugByKey is a method to get the translated word for a given key 
example:

```
for 'en' getSlugByKey('service') => 'Service'
for 'ar' getSlugByKey('service') => 'الخدمة'
```

if I browse my website in English language, and when I be in Mobile-App page, the URL is

```
http://localhost/example/public/en/service/mobile-app-development
```

when i click on a button to change the language, it returns to 404 page

how to do switch language and get translated URL at the same time?

thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is in the `getSlugByKey('service')` because the language is not yet changed !! it will return the slug of old language